# POS tagging - NLTK thinks noun is adjective

Tags: python, nltk

In the following code, why does nltk think 'fish' is an adjective and not a noun?

```
>>> import nltk
>>> s = "a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle"
>>> nltk.pos_tag(s.split())
[('a', 'DT'), ('woman', 'NN'), ('needs', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('man', 'NN'), ('like', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('fish', 'JJ'), ('needs', 'NNS'), ('a', 'DT'), ('bicycle', 'NN')]
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-ntlk-pos-tag-not-returnig-the-correct-pos

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is the workaround but you can check the source here https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk/nltk/tag/

Meanwhile I tried your sentence with little different approach.

```
>>> s = "a woman needs a man. A fish needs a bicycle"
>>> nltk.pos_tag(s.split())
[('a', 'DT'), ('woman', 'NN'), ('needs', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('man.', NP'), ('A','NNP'),   ('fish', 'NN'), ('needs', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('bicycle', 'NN')]
```

which resulted in fish as "NN".

Comment: I think it's because short sentences generally gets higher accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

If you used a Lookup Tagger as described in the [NLTK book, chapter 5](http://nltk.org/book/ch05.html) (for example using WordNet as lookup reference) first, your tagger would already "know" that *fish* cannot be an adjective. For all words with several possible POS Tags you could then use a statistical tagger as a backoff tagger.

Comment: Can you give an example of the statistical tagger you refer to at the end of your answer?

Comment: Most POS taggers in the NLTK make use of statistics of word / feature combinations. For example, [TNT](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.tnt.TnT) and [Naive Bayes](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you want `a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle` to get POS tags for such a "parse":

`[ [[a woman] needs [a man]] like [[a fish] needs [a bicycle]] ]`

but instead the NLTK default pos tagger isn't smart enough and gave you POS tag for such a parse:

`[ [[a woman] needs [a man]] like [a fish needs] [a bicycle] ]`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the POS tagger is given the input.  For example for the sentence:
"a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle"

If you use the default nltk word tokenizer and a regex tokenizer, the values will be different.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

TOKENIZER = RegexpTokenizer('(?u)\W+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')

s = "a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle"

regex_tokenize = TOKENIZER.tokenize(s)
default_tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(s)

regex_tag = nltk.pos_tag(regex_tokenize)
default_tag = nltk.pos_tag(default_tokenize)

print regex_tag
print "\n"
print default_tag
```

The output is as follows:

```
  Regex Tokenizer: 

[('a', 'DT'), (' ', 'NN'), ('woman', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('needs', 'NNS'), (' ', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), (' ', 'NN'), ('man', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('like', 'IN'), (' ', 'NN'), ('a', 'DT'), (' ', 'NN'), ('fish', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('needs', 'VBZ'), (' ', ':'), ('a', 'DT'), (' ', 'NN'), ('bicycle', 'NN')]

 Default Tokenizer: 

[('a', 'DT'), ('woman', 'NN'), ('needs', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('man', 'NN'), ('like', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('fish', 'JJ'), ('needs', 'NNS'), ('a', 'DT'), ('bicycle', 'NN')]
```

In Regex Tokenizer fish is a noun while in the default tokenizer fish is an adjective. 
  According to the tokenizer used, the parsing differs resulting in different parse tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) (3.5.1) then the phrase is correctly tagged:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
st = POSTagger("/.../stanford-postagger-full-2015-01-30/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger",
               "/.../stanford-postagger-full-2015-01-30/stanford-postagger.jar")
st.tag("a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle".split())
```

yields:

```
[('a', 'DT'),
 ('woman', 'NN'),
 ('needs', 'VBZ'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('man', 'NN'),
 ('like', 'IN'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('fish', 'NN'),
 ('needs', 'VBZ'),
 ('a', 'DT'),
 ('bicycle', 'NN')]
```